# Search within multiple values in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a Product Entity and it can have multiple attributes like applications. Where "applications" may have mutliple values too.

So the product has an array of values for "applications", how can I save that with Doctrine so I can do a findBy('applications' => 'whatever') or similar later?

```
Product 1
   application1
   application3

Product 2
   application1
   application2
```

So a later findBy('applications' => 'application1') should find both products.

Comment: you need to use DQL for that.

Comment: And you have to create a new entity call Applications. Then join Product and Application with a OneToMany relation.

After this, you can do a custom request with the Doctrine's DQL

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have configured a one to many relation between your entities, like this:

Product entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Aplication", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $aplications;
```

Aplication entity:

```
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="aplications")
* @ORM\JoinColumns({
*   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* })
    protected $product;
```

you can create a DQL like this on your product repository:

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('p')
   ->from('bundleNamespace:Product', 'p')
   ->leftJoin('p.applications', 'a')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('a.id', ':aplication'))
                    ->setParameter('aplication', $aplication);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function findProductByApplication($app) {
    $query = $this->em->createQuery('SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Product p JOIN p.applications app WHERE app = :app');
    $query->setParameter('app', $app);
    return $query->getResult();
}
```